# HandlerThread Synchronization on Object Creation

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have one thread that is waiting for a handler thread to create an object that it will initialize a pointer to. I read that you can't synchronize on a pointer's reference changing. How would I go about doing this?

I first tried having the thread return the object ,but that still didn't work.
Here is what I have so far.
"dataHolder" is the object that is being created and I want to wait on.
"lThread" is thread 2

Thread 1:

```
Data dataHolder= null;

        lThread.run();
        synchronized (lThread) {
            while(lThread.locked){

                try {

                    lThread.wait(3000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){

                }
            }
           dataHolder = lThread.dataHolder;
        }
```

Thread 2 's run method:

```
synchronized (this) {

            //get gps data
            LatLongAlt lla = getLatLonAlt();
            if (lla == null) {
                return;
            }
            //create image data holder
            dataHolder = new Data(lla, mSensor.getAzimuth(), -1 * mSensor.getPitch(), mSensor.getRoll());
            //get four corner geo locations
            GeotagActivity gT = new GeotagActivity(dataHolder.getLatLonAlt(), dataHolder.getAzimuth(), dataHolder.getPitch(), dataHolder.getRoll());
            //create four corners holder
            FourCorners fc = new FourCorners(gT.getTopLeft(), gT.getTopRight(), gT.getBottomLeft(), gT.getBottomRight());
            //set four corners
            dataHolder.setFourCorners(fc);
            locked = false;
            this.notify();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Data dataHolder= null;

    lThread.setLocked(true);
    lThread.run();
        while(lThread.isLocked()){

            try {

                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
       dataHolder = lThread.dataHolder;
```

Thread 2 's run method:

```
        //get gps data
        LatLongAlt lla = getLatLonAlt();
        if (lla == null) {
            return;
        }
        //create image data holder
        dataHolder = new Data(lla, mSensor.getAzimuth(), -1 * mSensor.getPitch(), mSensor.getRoll());
        //get four corner geo locations
        GeotagActivity gT = new GeotagActivity(dataHolder.getLatLonAlt(), dataHolder.getAzimuth(), dataHolder.getPitch(), dataHolder.getRoll());
        //create four corners holder
        FourCorners fc = new FourCorners(gT.getTopLeft(), gT.getTopRight(), gT.getBottomLeft(), gT.getBottomRight());
        //set four corners
        dataHolder.setFourCorners(fc);
        setLocked(false);
        this.notify();
```

make getter and setter for locked:

```
public synchronized boolean isLocked() {
    return locked;
}

public synchronized void setLocked(boolean locked) {
    this.locked = locked;
}
```

Basically you locked the lThread out forever by synchronizing the whole process on it. You suppose to only synchronize the points of the interactions.